# How to develop custom query builder in my application?

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, builder

I want to develop select query builder in my vb.net application. If user write the "select query" in a richtext box that query will be executed and the result will be displayed in a grid view. Any one send the Sample Application for this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, look at [this answer on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/161242/Binding-a-DataReader-in-a-GridView-in-WinForm#answer3):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdQuery = new SqlCommand("Your Query Here", con);
            SqlDataReader drQuery = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader();
            DataSet dsQuery = new DataSet();
            DataTable dtQuery = new DataTable();
            dsQuery.Tables.Add(dtQuery);
            dsQuery.Load(drQuery, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, dsQuery.Tables[0]);
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dsQuery.Tables[0];
```

A recommendation: Never let your users enter SQL directly. You should do everything you can to avoid this since you loose control of both security and performance.

What if a user runs a "DELETE FROM dbo.Orders" or a very complex query consuming all available memory?

If it's for DBAs or developers they should be capable of using development tools like [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) or such.

**UPDATE:**
Working example for validating SQL:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ParentID";
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(sql, "^SELECT([^;])$",System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
// do something
}
else
{
throw new InvalidOperationException("You're not allowed to execute nothing but SELECT-queries.");
}
```

Comment: This is what i did already, but I want to restrict the user to execute only "select" command, and also user has given the capability to execute the join queries too. Please help me to do this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example on how to validate the sql. It requires the query to start with "SELECT" and cannot contain ; which restricts the user from adding addtional commands like DELETE and such after.